# Please explain this code in Mathematica that creates a heat / intensity map

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

```
Graphics@Flatten[Table[

(*colors, dont mind*)
{ColorData["CMYKColors"][(a[[r, t]] - .000007)/(.0003 - 0.000007)], 

(*point size, dont mind*)
PointSize[1/Sqrt[r]/10], 

(*Coordinates for your points "a" is your data matrix *)
   Point[
        {(rr =Log[.025 + (.58 - .25)/64 r]) Cos@(tt = t 5 Degree), 
          rr Sin@tt}]
        } &@

 (*values for the iteration*)
 , {r, 7, 64}, {t, 1, 72}], 1] 

 (*Rotation, dont mind*)
 /. gg : Graphics[___] :> Rotate[gg, Pi/2]
```

Comment: For the Mma Community here: this is a followup of this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161814/creating-spectral-heat-maps-or-intensity-maps-from-cdip-data-using-ruby. I can't refine it right now.

Answer (score 7):

Okay, I'll bite.  First, Mathematica allows functions to be applied via one of [several forms](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SpecialWaysToInputExpressions.html): standard form - `f[x]`, prefix form - `f @ x`, postfix form - `f // x`, and infix form - `x ~ f ~ y`.  Belisarius's code uses both standard and prefix form.

So, let's look at the outermost functions first:  `Graphics @ x /. gg : Graphics[___]:> Rotate[gg,Pi/2]`, where `x` is everything inside of `Flatten`.  Essentially, what this does is create a `Graphics` object from `x` and using a [named pattern](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Pattern.html?q=Pattern&lang=en) (`gg : Graphics[___]`) rotates the resulting `Graphics` object by 90 degrees.

Now, to create a `Graphics` object, we need to supply a bunch of primitives and this is in the form of a nested list, where each sublist describes some element. This is done via the [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Table.html?q=Table&lang=en) command which has the form: `Table[ expr, iterators ]`.  Iterators can have several forms, but here they both have the form `{var, min, max}`, and since they lack a 4th term, they take on each value between `min` and `max` in integer steps. So, our iterators are `{r, 7, 64}` and `{t, 1, 72}`, and `expr` is evaluated for each value that they take on.  Since, we have two iterators this produces a matrix, which would confuse `Graphics`, so we using `Flatten[ Table[ ... ], 1]` we take every element of the matrix and put it into a simple list.

Each element that `Table` produces is simply: color (`ColorData`), point size (`PointSize`), and point location (`Point`). So, with `Flatten`, we have created the following:

```
Graphics[{{color, point size, point}, {color, point size, point}, ... }]
```

The color generation is taken from the data, and it assumes that the data has been put into a list called `a`.  The individual elements of `a` are accessed through the `Part` construct: [`[[]]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorData.html?q=ColorData&lang=en).  On the surface, the `ColorData` construct is a little odd, but it can be read as `ColorData["CMYKColors"]` returns a [`ColorDataFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorData.html?q=ColorData&lang=en) that produces a CMYK color value when a value between 0 and 1 is supplied.  That is why the data from `a` is scaled the way it is.

The point size is generated from the radial coordinate.  You'd expect with `1/Sqrt[r]` the point size should be getting smaller as `r` increases, but the `Log` inverts the scale.

Similarly, the point location is produced from the radial and angular (`t`) variables, but `Point` only accepts them in `{x,y}` form, so he needed to convert them.  Two odd constructs occur in the transformation from `{r,t}` to `{x,y}`: both `rr` and `tt` are [Set](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Set.html?q=Set&lang=en) (`=`) while calculating `x` allowing them to be used when calculating `y`.  Also, the term `t 5 Degree` lets Mathematica know that the angle is in degrees, not radians.  Additionally, as written, there is a bug:  immediately following the closing `}`, the terms `&` and `@` should not be there.

Does that help?

Comment: Setting variables like that (rr & tt) is a new one for me! Brilliant. Point is closed after the Sin, the formatting is dodgy though.

Comment: @Timo, didn't see the closing bracket, updated answer. But, it still shouldn't have the `&@`. Using `Set` like that is unusual, but perfectly legal and the vars are set prior to use.

Comment: @Timo @rcollyer Nice analysis +1. The &@ is a leftover of a previous version. Please note the rr calculation  inverts the polar r "axis". That is why you see the points increasing in size

Comment: @belisarius: I've added a simpler bit of code to the original problem. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161814/creating-spectral-heat-maps-or-intensity-maps-from-cdip-data-using-ruby/5173581#5173581

Comment: @belisarius, yep, I didn't think through what `Log` would do.  fixed.